# Bulk load data conversion error

Tags: sql-server, csv

i'm having this problem for quite a few days, and after searching online, still unable to fix it. If anyone could help me, ill be very grateful!

**This is the error i'm getting:**

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 31 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for
>   row 12, column 12 (SalesRepEmployeeNumber).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 31 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for
>   row 14, column 13 (CreditLimit).

**Heres my SQL Codings** 
**Create Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE Customers1
(
    CustomerNumber INT NOT NULL,
    CustomerName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ContactLastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ContactFirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Phone VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    AddressLine1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    AddressLine2 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    City VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    State VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    PostalCode VARCHAR(15) NULL,
    Country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    SalesRepEmployeeNumber INT NULL,
    CreditLimit MONEY NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerNumber)
);
```

**Code to bulk insert:**

```
BULK INSERT Customers1
FROM 'C:\Customers.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

**The file I am trying to import from is a csv file, some example of the contents are:**

```
124, Mini Gifts Distributors Ltd., Nelson, Valarie, 4155551450, 5677 Strong St.,        San Rafael, CA      ,USA    ,1165   ,210500
125,    Havel & Zbyszek Co  ,Piestrzeniewicz    ,Zbyszek    ,(26) 642-7555  ,ul. Filtrowa 68    ,   Warszawa    ,   01-012, Poland  ,   ,   0
```

**Row 12:** 144,    Volvo Model Replicas, Co,   Berglund    ,Christina  ,0921-12 3555   ,Berguvsvägen  8    ,   Luleå   ,  ,    S-958 22    ,Sweden ,1504   ,53100

**Row 14:** 146,    Saveley & Henriot, Co., Saveley,    Mary,   78.32.5555, 2, rue du Commerce,     Lyon,       69004,  France, 1337,   123900

Comment: in row 12 there are only 12 values while you need 13

Comment: there was actually a blank, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
144, Volvo Model Replicas, Co, Berglund
146, Saveley & Henriot, Co., Saveley
```

In your second field there's a comma, which is also your seperator.

**To fix**, remove those comma's (while generating the file), or quote the fields like this:

```
144, "Volvo Model Replicas, Co", Berglund
146, "Saveley & Henriot, Co.", Saveley
```

You might want to check other fields too, for example:

```
, 2, rue du Commerce,
```

You might also want to remove the spaces around your fields, or quote them where needed - some parsers can have problems with leading spaces. Also check your raw data to see if there are no special hidden characters.

Also make sure you don't have any multiline fields in the other rows, because that might cause even more shifting of malformed fields.

Comment: I do not believe that's the problem. Yes, those "Co" values get dropped into column Contact Last Name, making everything "off" by one column--but only up through City. There is no State value for these rows, and everything lines up at column PostalCode and after--which includes the two problem columns.

Comment: @PhilipKelley - Oh, I'm sorry, I thought this comment was from the OP.. (made my heartbeat go up some..) - only now I see it's your comment :) - Anyhow, after 'quite a few days', it might be time to fix those most obvious problems first (I wonder how an invoice might look like, with most of the fiedls shifted).

Comment: I only addressed the BULK INSERT error issues in my reply, but yes, I think they've got a number of data issues to deal with there. (And heck yeah, "extra spaces" stuff can be insidious...)

Comment: @PhilipKelley - Indeed, but meanwhile a had deleted part of that update, so the comment 'see update' isn't valid anymore (and was in fact addressed at the OP, but I had seen it totally wrong).

Answer (score 0):

You do appear to have a data problem, as @Danny_ds points out, but that alone does not explain your errors. Looking at just your sample set, I do not see any obvious problems regarding data loading, though (as per my comment to @Danny_ds's post) I think the data you'd load here ends up wonky.

Some guesses as to what's going on:

- There may be "Euro characters" (such as that ä and the å) that throw things off.  I'm speaking mostly through fear and ignorance here, the very very few times I've had to deal with such I've always hit snags in my Ameri-centric coding tools.
- There may be issues in preceding lines that carry over to these lines.
- How sure are your line-ending markers? "End of line" character problems can be notoriously awful to debug; "/n" isn't actually character, and if either/or of ascii 13 + 10 are not present , you can be in a world of pain. (And they both have to be there on every line--maybe the generating system or file transmission system cut something off?)

One way to "debug" stuff like this is to break down your import file. Make a copy, remove lines, see if it still loads, then repeat. For example, try loading the file with:

- All lines after 11 deleted
- Lines 12 and 14 deleted
- All lines up to 10, then 11, deleted
- Only lines 12 and 14 present

Do this and you can narrow down where the problem is actually cropping up. Good luck!